# Get Flatlist ItemSeparatorComponent trailing item?

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

The Flatlist lets you define an [ItemSeparatorComponent](https://reactnative.dev/docs/0.48/flatlist#itemseparatorcomponent) that receive as default props `highlighted` and `leadingItem`. The leading Item represents the item displayed **before** the Separator.

The problem is that I am using `inverted` on my Flatlist and my Seperators now need to adapt to the next item instead of the previous one.

Is there any way to access the item displayed **after** the Separator? Something like a trailingItem?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want to have the trailing item, you can use `separators.updateProps` to add a custom property. Below I have used the example from the [FlatList docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#renderitem) and modified it slightly. In this example we are highlighting the trailing separator of the clicked item and we are adding the `trailingItem` to the props of `ItemSeparatorComponent`.

#**Output:**

[image: Output]

#**Code:**

JSX:

```
<View style={styles.container}>
  <FlatList
    ItemSeparatorComponent={(props) => {
      console.log('props', props); // here you can access the trailingItem with props.trailingItem
      return (<View style={{height: 5, backgroundColor: props.highlighted ? 'green' : 'gray'}} />);
    }}
    data={data}
    inverted
    renderItem={({item, index, separators}) => renderItem(item,index,separators)}
  />
</View>
```

renderItem:

```
const renderItem = (item, index, separators) => {
   return (
     <TouchableHighlight
       key={item.key}
       onPress={() => console.log('onPress')}
       onShowUnderlay={() => separators.updateProps('trailing', {trailingItem: data[index+1], highlighted: true})}
       onHideUnderlay={() => separators.updateProps('trailing', {trailingItem: data[index+1], highlighted: false})}>
       <View style={{backgroundColor: 'white', height: 50, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}>
         <Text>{item.id}</Text>
       </View>
     </TouchableHighlight>
  );
}
```

#**Explanation:**

The whole magic happens here:

```
onShowUnderlay={() => separators.updateProps('trailing', {trailingItem: data[index+1], highlighted: true})}
```

From the docs we can see, that updateProps expects the following two parameters:

> select (enum('leading', 'trailing'))
>
> newProps (Object)

First we select `trailing`, afterwards we can add our custom prop. We are adding the `trailingItem` prop and we are overriding the `highlighted` prop. Now we can access our props in the ItemSeparatorComponent with props.trailingItem (see above, i leaved a comment on the specific line).

#**Working Example:**

https://snack.expo.io/@tim1717/flatlist-separators

Comment: This will only set trailingItem when the TouchableHighlight is pressed, wouldn't it? I would like to be able to access it before any input from the user.

Comment: @RyanPergent in this example yes, but if think you can use `separator.updateProps` wherever you want (even without user interaction)

Comment: The only thing I can think about is to call updateProps every time an item is mounted. Is this how it is meant to be? Isn't it expensive?

Comment: @RyanPergent You can try it out, if it's too expensive you will notice. Another idea would be to evaluate the current scroll position and on base of that you can set the traillingItem? I don't know your exact use case, but maybe this would help ;)